# Connect a specific port in webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode6, port

How can I load an UIwebView with a specific port, when I try on xcode6, nothing is displayed in the simulator ...

I have use this code :

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myurl.com:9090";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

With this code, webview is not load ...

Answer (score 0):

Hello Everything is OK no issue in url  plz try correct url

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307882";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: With https , and this URL it's ok but with my specific port ( 9092 ) , it's not ok , so why and how can I resolv the problem ?

Comment: may be url is not correct some issue in Your Url that why Cant open iniWebView

Comment: My url is correct , in safari on my iPhone and the simularor it's loaded